# Convert Varchar2 to Date - with Case/Decode/IIF statement and set a null value in 1 condition

Tags: oracle

I have a column with varchar2(4000) as datatype. However, this column has following type of values
'//'
'112/01/01'
this column is date column

I would like to get the following output-
IF '//' then set it NULL
IF '112/01/01' then set it as 2012/01/01

I am having issue when i use a case/decode/iif statement and set the value as NULL.

I tried the following SQL statement and it gives me either ORA-00932 error or Ora-01841 error.

Here are my statements:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN DATE_CATALOG_SENT = '//' THEN to_date('1950/01/01'), 'yyyy/mm/dd')
     ELSE TO_DATE(substr(DATE_CATALOG_SENT, 2, LENGTH(DATE_CATALOG_SENT)),'yyyy/mm/dd')
END AS abcd
FROM 
DUAL;

SELECT  CASE WHEN DATE_CATALOG_SENT = 0 THEN 'NULL'
             ELSE TO_DATE(substr(DATE_CATALOG_SENT, 2,  LENGTH(DATE_CATALOG_SENT)),'yy/mm/dd') 
END 
FROM DUAL;
```

Is there a way to fix this problem using SQL query only and not PL/SQL?

Thanks
AD

Comment: If the input is `'//'` then you want the result to be `null`, or `1950/01/01`? Please make up your mind, then edit the post to correct it one way or the other. Also: when the input is `'112/01/01'`, if you remove the first character and then use the model `'yyyy/mm/dd'` the year will become 12 AD, is that really what you want?

Comment: Ideally, I want to make it Null.But as I was not able to do it, I was substituting it with some lowest date.

Comment: You were right, as I used yy/mm/dd format the query run when i used 195/01/01 as the lowest date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
with inputs (dt_str) as (
  select '//'        from dual union all
  select '112/01/01' from dual
)
select dt_str,
       to_date(to_char(19000000 + to_number(replace(dt_str, '/')), 'fm00000000')
       , 'yyyymmdd') as resulting_dt
from   inputs
;

DT_STR    RESULTING_DT           
--------- -----------------------
//                               
112/01/01 2012-01-01
```

That is: first remove the slashes; the string becomes either empty (`NULL`) or a seven-digit string. Convert the resulting string to a number, then add 19000000 to it; the sum is still `NULL` if the initial string was just `'//'`, and otherwise - after converting back to string - it becomes a proper representation of a date as a string, in `yyyymmdd` format. Use `to_date(...)` to finally convert it to a date. If the input was `'//'`, the resulting date will be `NULL`.

If instead of null you want the date to default to 1950-01-01 when the input is `'//'`, you can wrap the entire `to_date(...)` expression within `NVL(......., date '1950-01-01')`

Comment: Now this worked which somehow was not working yesterday                          SELECT CASE WHEN DATE_1 = '//' THEN null
            ELSE TO_DATE(substr(DATE_1, 2, LENGTH(DATE_1)),'yy/mm/dd')
END AS abcd
FROM Dual;